# Flutter build TabBarView items via server response

Tags: flutter, dart

in one of our mobile application we have a simple screen which we want to make `TabBarView` pages via result of server response, for example if server response this collection:

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      /* has 3 children */
      "category_item": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sample"
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "sample 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "sample 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "sample 1"
        }
      ]
    },
      /* has 2 children */
    {
      "category_item": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "test"
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "test 1"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "test 1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

we should have 2 `Tab`s as `sample` and `test` with some children inside `TabBarView` relatives with parent category, for example first index of array has 3 children and second index of array has 2 children.

our problem is `TabController` that when we retrieve data from server, screen has been built and we can't manage this action. I mean this tab and `TabBarView` children should be built with response data. basically time I passed zero to `TabController` because server doesn't response in this time and after getting data I get error on length of that,

```dart
class SelectClothesScreenState extends State<SelectClothesScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  CategoryProducts _cats;
  List<Products> _productList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _getCats();
  }

  bool _isLoading = true;

  _getCats() async {
    final CategoryProducts response = await Api.apiCatList();
    List<Products> _p = [];
    setState(() {
      _cats = response;
      _productList = _p;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    _tabController = TabController(length: _cats == null ? 0 : _cats.categories.length ?? 0, vsync: this);
  }

  Widget loadingView() {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var fullWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            //address and search icon and close icon
            Container(
              height: 50,
              child: _cats != null && _isLoading
                  ? loadingView()
                  : ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      itemCount: _cats == null ? 0 : _cats.categories.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        print(_cats.categories.length);
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            print(index);
                            _tabController.animateTo(index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 750), curve: Curves.ease);
                          },
                          child: CatItem(catView: _cats.categories[index].categoryItem),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
            ),
            //content grid list product and btn confirm
            Container(
              width: fullWidth,
              child: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
                //grid product list
                ...List.generate(_cats == null ? 0 : _cats.categories.length, (index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: fullWidth,
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: _productList.length,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(color: Colors.black);
                        //return ProductView(productView: _productList[index]);
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }
}
```

how can I set correct implementation for length of `TabController` after retrieving data from server? thanks in advance